# How to do replace on multiple files with powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

The aim is replace ",," with blank in the text files.
[image]

The below works on single file:

```
$path = "C:\Users\ThompsonHo\Desktop\testing\F181RMR CAN.txt"
$word = ",,"
$replacement = ""
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
```

I try to make it handle for multiple files but fail, How to do replace on multiple files with powershell?

```
$path = "C:\Users\ThompsonHo\Desktop\testing\F18*.txt"
$word = ",,"
$replacement = ""
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
```

Comment: this is work for my case.    Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ThompsonHo\Desktop\testing *.txt -recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
        $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
        $c = $c -replace ',,',''
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
    }

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve a list of files, then iterate over the list.

You can retrieve files that match a pattern with `Get-ChildItem` (although `Get-Item` would also work in this situation):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\ThompsonHo\Desktop\testing\F18*.txt"
```

That gives you an array of `FileInfo`. You can iterate over a collection with `foreach`.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file.FullName
}
```

`$file.FullName` at this point will be the full path to the file.

Your existing working solution for a single file should be easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p="C:\temp"
$cs=Get-ChildItem -Path $p 

foreach($c in $cs)
{
    $t=Get-Content -Path $c.FullName -Raw 
    #$t  -replace ",,",""|Out-File -FilePath  $c.FullName -NoNewline
    Set-Content -Path $c.FullName -Value ($t  -replace ",,","") -NoNewline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\F18*.txt" | %{$file=$_.FullName; (Get-Content $file).Replace(',,', ',') | Out-File $file }
```